# jqgrid - resize column width on ipad

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to resize columns width on ipad ? It works on chrome on my laptop but not on the ipad.

The resizable option for the ColModel API is enabled by default so it should work...I would need a hack for the module code.

```
    jQuery('#list3').jqGrid({
    url:'/grid?id=2',
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Id','customerName', 'contractID'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'_id',index:'_id', width:50, editable:true},
        {name:'customerName',index:'customerName', width:300, editable:true},
        {name:'contracts.contractID',index:'contractID', width:200,align:"right", editable:true},
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager3',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Customers Read only all values",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "_id",
        root: function (obj) {
            return obj;
        },
        records: function (obj) {
            return obj.length;
        },
        page: function (obj) {
            return 1;
        },
        total: function (obj) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

});
jQuery('#list3').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager3',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Thanks